# How to prevent modified apps from running in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In testing, they are able to do these things.

- unpack the packages
- modify something
- repack the packages

And installed and the system can still work

From what happened I got the following advice as follows:
The Application should check for binary and package integrity before being allowed to be executed.

In my opinion
Can I check the md5sum runtime? and is there any way to prevent the tampered app to be running? Please tell me which way I can do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

"The client is in the hands of the enemy".

If you want something tamper-proof, move that logic to the server and make sure your client can authenticate properly.

---

> From what happened I got the following advice as follows: The Application should check for binary and package integrity before being allowed to be executed.

That is a fools errand. Anybody who can tamper with your package can obviously also tamper with your code to check your own integrity.

You need a system that your user *cannot* tamper with to check integrity of packages. And on the user's own device, that simply does not exist. They are the *owner* of the device. They can manipulate it in any way they see fit.

Maybe you can elaborate on "what happened" and who gave you this advice. Normally, the person giving such advice should be the first to ask for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I've edited the question to provide more information. Please guide me.

Comment: That's a good reason, Thanks. have a good day.